# Instantiating an abstract class in Rhino interpreter in Java Scripting

Tags: java, abstract-class, rhino

I am using `javax.script.*` with Rhino for scripting in a Java program.

A script can implement an interface just fine, but when I try to use similar syntax to instantiate an abstract class(giving the definitions for the unimplemented methods) I get an error saying that `MyTestAbstractClass`(the class I am trying to instantiate) is an interface or abstract. Am I doing something very wrong?

This is the Javascript code I am using:

```
var testObject  = new foo.mytestpackage.TestAbstractClass() {
    printMessage: function() {
        print("foo");
    }
};
```

When `TestAbstractClass` is a class with a normal constructor(no parameters), I get the following stacktrace:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: error instantiating (JavaAdapter: first arg should be interface Class (<Unknown source>#1)): class com.merkle.TestObject is interface or abstract (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using Sun's (slightly simplified, as I have heard) Rhino implementation, and using the official Rhino jars is something I'd like to avoid as they're pretty large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's [release notes for Java 7's JavaScript Engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/#jsengine) suggest that instantiating abstract types is not supported:

> Rhino's `JavaAdapter` has been overridden. `JavaAdapter` is the feature by which Java class can be extended by JavaScript and Java interfaces may be implemented by JavaScript. We have replaced Rhino's `JavaAdapter` with our own implementation of `JavaAdapter`. In our implementation, only single Java interface may be implemented by a JavaScript object.

This seems to be borne out by the error message:

```
JavaAdapter: first arg should be interface Class (<Unknown source>#1)
```

You'll have to implement the type in Java and consume the implementation if you aren't willing to switch engines.

Comment: Could you clarify "consume the implementation"?

Comment: I mean you'll have to write a non-abstract class (e.g. `Foo`) in Java extending the abstract type and then just use that in your Rhino code (e.g. `var f = new Foo();`)

Comment: Ah, OK. So I could also, if I needed abstract methods, pass in the necessary interface? Could the interface be a nested type?